# JavaScript Trying to Print The Number of Times a Letter Appears In String But It Prints More than Once

Tags: javascript, algorithm

In the code below, I am trying to check how many times a letter in a string appears. Problem with the code below is that it prints each letter more than once. It needs to collect all the same letters and show the number of times it occurs in the string and display it once.

```js
const string = 'mississippi'

const letters = [...string]

let currentLetter = ''
let letterOccurance = []


for(let i = 0; i < letters.length; i++){
  let letterFrequency = letters.filter((letter)=>{
    return letter === letters[i]
  })

  letterOccurance.push([`${letters[i]}`,letterFrequency.length])
}

console.log(letterOccurance)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's too much code just to get the number of times a letter appears in a string. Try the following code:

```js
const string = 'mississippi';

let frequency = {};

for (let letter of string) {
  if (frequency[letter]) {
    frequency[letter]++;
  } else {
    frequency[letter] = 1;
  }
}

console.log(frequency);
```

Comment: That's a pretty elegant solution. I would have started with a Set of letters.

Comment: You can easily turn it into a reduce with a ternary `[...string].reduce((freq, c) => (freq[c] ? freq[c]++ : freq[c] = 1, freq), {})`

Comment: Here's the Set version (since I had to see it). `[...(new Set(string))].map(c => [c, [...string].filter(d => d == c).length])` Looks a bit messy imo.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't realize there was such a simple solution like this.

Answer (score 7):

You're always pushing the letter to the array, whether it already exists there or not:

```
letterOccurance.push([`${letters[i]}`,letterFrequency.length])
```

You could check if it exists first:

```
if (!letterOccurance.find(l => l[0] === letters[i])) {
  letterOccurance.push([`${letters[i]}`,letterFrequency.length])
}
```

Or even skip it entirely if you've already seen it, since the first time you find any letter you already know its complete count:

```
for(let i = 0; i < letters.length; i++){
  if (letterOccurance.find(l => l[0] === letters[i])) {
    continue;
  }
  // the rest of the loop...
}
```

There's honestly a variety of ways you could step back and re-approach the problem.  But for the question about why letters are repeating, that's simply because each iteration of the loop unconditionally appends the letter to the resulting array.

Answer (score 1):

How about writing a more generic item-counting function and then layering `countLetters` as a simple partial application of the identity function?

```js
const countBy = (fn) => ([...xs]) =>
  xs .reduce ((a, x) => {const k = fn (x); a [k] = (a[k] || 0) + 1; return a}, {})

const countLetters = countBy (x => x)

console .log (countLetters ('missisippi'))
```

`countBy` is fairly generic.  You pass it a function to convert your values to strings, and pass your array of items to the function it returns.  Strings are array-like enough that this just works for our simple `countLetters`.  But we could use it for other counts as well, such as:

```js
countBy (x => x .grade) ([{id: 1, grade: 'A'}, {id: 2, grade: 'B'}, {id: 3, grade: 'A'}])
//=> {"A": 2, "B": 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using a `Set` to get the individual letters and `String.split()` to count.

```js
const countChars = str => Object.fromEntries(
  [...new Set(str)]
  .map(c => [c, str.split(c).length-1])
)

console.log(countChars('mississippi'));
```

Using `reduce` to build the object

```js
const countChars = str => [...str].reduce(
  (a, c) => (a[c] ? a[c]++ : a[c]=1, a),
  {}
) 

console.log(countChars('mississippi'));
```

var result =